# Open deeper activity from notification with dependent parents

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

In my application i have the case that i want to open an activity from a notification. 
The activity to open depends on initializations from parent activities.

App start **=>** Splashscreen Activity (initialize services, ...) **=>** Login Activity **=>** Main Activity (load data from web) **=>** Detail Activity (show one specific data)

Right now i am passing the id for the specific data throug all these activities and decide wether to continue without user input (when coming from notification) or not.

I was wondering if this is a common way to do this or if my base setup is wrong already. (initializing in splashscren, etc.)

Do i have to take out the initializations completly from the activities and put them into 'services'?

Comment: You should externalize your initialization code as it seems multiple components (`Activity`s) want to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple components (Activitys) want to use it" ?

The dependency? That the main activity relies on initializations happening in the splash screen?

Oh maybe i should've mentioned, the actual initialization is happening in the Application class, though is started by the splash screen and when done the splash screen is notified that the initialization is finished.

Comment: I meant make the code reusable. If you can explain what exactly are you initializing and your app flow, perhaps me or someone here can provide more inputs.

Comment: In my application class i have an initialization method that returns an observable (working with RxJava).

The observable is subscribed to in my splashscreen.

The observable is emitting values for seperate steps done, so i can show a progress in the UI.

I am initializing things like, the google Apis, Picasso Loader, BitmapDescriptors, Firebase, Facebook Sdk, ...

When finished, my SplashScreen starts the Login activity.

The user can choose to sign in or don't.

Then the MainActivity is started and the data of my app is loaded (shops in this case)

Comment: You can store the state of your initialization as an `Application` class variable which is global and accessible to all components like `Activity` and `Service`. You can use this variable and set/reset it to initialize or unload libraries in your Activity life cycle methods. Also, to initialize, yes you can use a `Service`.

Comment: I'm already using the `Application` class as i mentioned. I'm having all my Services in variables there. It's just that i am STARTING the initialization in my splash screen. And i need to wait for the initializations to finish...